# Compile Python Program include imports

Tags: python, compilation

I wrote a Python program on my Mac running Python 2.7.10.

It's just 1 single .py file. 
The first few lines of the program are like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import clipboard
import time
import sys
import os
import pyperclip
import re

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("SO_site-packages"))
```

I want to compile this .py file to an .exe that can be run on any Windows machine.

I thus want to include the imported libraries in the .exe.

Is this even possible? If yes, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac you need this package: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

call it using: `pyinstaller -F myscript.py`

You can use py2exe if you're under windows: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

You will create a separate setup.py that will call your python script.

Comment: I've tried it but I'm not sure if I did it right. I ended up with 2 folders. 'build' and 'dist'. The 'dist' folder contains a folder named 'py-clipboard' (my program) which in turn contains a file called 'py-clipboard'. Now what do I do?

Comment: try this ! pyinstaller -F myscript.py